# Jordan Decomposition of Self Adjoint Functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Im reading over the following theorem in C* algebras by Murphy, and I'm confused on two particular parts:
[image]

[image]

1:  How is Hahn Banach being applied here exactly?  What linear functional are we extending to somehow conclude there exists a $\rho \in C(\Omega,\mathbb{R})^{\sharp}$ (the dual over $\mathbb{R}$) with $\rho \circ \theta = \tau'$?

2:  How is $\theta$ isometric?  Theorem $3.3.6$ states for $a \in A$ a normal elemnent of a nonzero $C^{*}$ algebra, there exists a state $\tau \in A^{*}$ with $||a|| = |\tau(a)|$.  From this theorem, clearly $||a|| \leq ||\theta(a)||_{\infty}$, but the other direction is confusing me.

My only guess is that if you apply the Gelfand representation to $C^{*}(a)$, then $\sup_{\Omega'}|\hat{a}(\tau)| = ||\theta(a)||_{\infty} \leq ||\hat{a}||_{\infty} = ||a||$ where $\Omega'$ is the set of all positive linear functionals on $C^{*}(a)$ with norm $\leq 1$.  Then the restrictions of all the positive linear functionals on $A$ withh norm $\leq 1$ are contained in $\Omega'$, and since all of the functionals are acting only on a fixed $a$, $|\tau|_{C^{*}(a)}(a)| = |\tau(a)|$ for $\tau \in \Omega$, and hence $\sup_{\tau \in \Omega'} |\tau(a)| \geq ||\theta(a)|| \implies $ equality.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You choose a sequence $\{a_k\}\subset A_{\rm sa}$ with $$\tag1\lim\tau(a_k)=\|\tau\|.$$ Let $M=\theta(A_{\rm sa})\subset C(\Omega,\mathbb R)$. Then consider $\rho_0:M:\to\mathbb R$ given by $\rho_0(\theta(a))=\tau(a)$.
   Then
   $$
   |\rho_0(\theta(a))|=|\tau'(a)|\leq\|\tau'\|\,\|a\|=\|\tau'\|\,\|\theta(a)\|,
   $$
   and from  $(1)$ you get $\|\rho_0\|=\|\tau'\|$;   now you apply Hahn-Banach to extend to all of $C(\Omega,\mathbb R)$.
2. By definition $\|\tau\|\leq1$ for all $\tau\in\Omega$, so $$|\theta(a)(\tau)|=|\tau(a)|\leq\|\tau\|\,\|a\|=\|a\|.$$

Comment: Thank you! On 1) how do we know there exists a a_0 that maximizes the functional?  Is this because the closed unit ball of A_sa is weakly compact?

Comment: Actually on second pass, it looks like 1) works just by the fact that there exists a sequence $(a_k) \subset A_{sa}$ in the closed unit ball such that $\lim \tau(a_k) = ||\tau||$ right? The definition of $\rho_0$ seems to make this work

Comment: Yes, you are right. The $a_0$ might not exist, but the argument works fine with the sequence as you say.